# How to update specific XML tag values using a shell script?

Tags: xml, shell

The following is a part of a XML where I want to change `username` and `password` with any desired values.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName">
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property name="url">
    <value>jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/app
    </value>
  </property>
  <property name="username">
    <value>user1</value>
  </property>
  <property name="password">
    <value>pass1</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The values (`<value>` tags) of `username` and `password` properties may contain anything, e.g. `user1`, `pass1`, `user2`, `pass2`, etc.
How do I update these strings with different values in a shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) command updates the password value in `source.xml` file according to XPath expression:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
  -u "//bean[@id='dataSource']//property[@name='password']/value" \
  -v 'new_pass' source.xml
```

Note, the double slash (`//`) in the XPath expression selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are (*read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp), for example*). I've included it into the expression, because I suspect that the XML you mentioned in the question has a number of parent nodes.

If there is a namespace declared, you should specify it explicitly. For example, if the root element is declared as `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">`, then you should specify the namespace using `-N` global option:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
  -N x=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans \
  -u "//x:bean//x:property[@name='password']/x:value" \
  -v 'new_pass' source.xml
```

*This is just a sample command that will work with XML you posted in the question. If you have different structure, adjust the XPath expression accordingly.*

**source.xml** *(before running the command)*

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName">
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property name="url">
    <value>jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/app
    </value>
  </property>
  <property name="username">
    <value>user1</value>
  </property>
  <property name="password">
    <value>pass1</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

**source.xml** *(after running the command)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName">
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property name="url">
    <value>jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/app
    </value>
  </property>
  <property name="username">
    <value>user1</value>
  </property>
  <property name="password">
    <value>new_pass</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: @user3777747, have you installed xmlstarlet?

Comment: Yes, I have installed xmlstarlet.

Comment: @user3777747, then _how_ is it "not working"? Any error messages?

Comment: No, There is no any error message. When I run this command, it shows the content of xml file. But there is no changes found for the password .

Comment: @user3777747, I've updated my answer. With _this_ XML the command _will_ work. But if you have different structure, or there is no `bean` tag with `id="dataSource"`, then it will not work due to the XPath. So if your XML differs from the one mentioned in the question, you should adjust the XPath accordingly. Note the double slash in the XPath expression. It fetches _all bean tags with id equal to `dataSource`. This is for the case, if this tag has a parent node.

Comment: Hi, I have run this updated command. This show the updated content after  running the command but on viewing the file, changes does not reflected.

Comment: @user3777747, are you sure you have used `--inplace `? Read the output of `xmlstarlet ed --help`. Maybe in your specific version this option is spelled differently

Comment: Thanks. But this works for that sample xml which we used in Question(Not in my actual xml file). and I haven't enough reputation to post a xml having  multiple link. So, Please share your email or something, where i can forward u that complete xml. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @user3777747, I would recommend describing the XML structure in the question in details. At least, draw a scheme like `<my-root-tag> / <beans> / <bean>...<bean>...`. You can add a link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with the full XML to the question. But your issue is likely that you haven't adjusted the `id` in XPath expression.

Comment: Please find gist link https://gist.github.com/User37777477/1c943f2830c1ede1332eca0d76da23a5

Comment: @user3777747, you need `-N` option. I've added a sample

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be help you and you may change however you want  ;

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
echo "usage: argument 1:username 2:password"
exit 1
fi
USERNAME=$1
PASSWORD=$2


echo "Change values in config.xml..."

cat <<EOF >test.xml
<bean id="dataSource"
                  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName">
                    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
            </property>
            <property name="url">
                    <value>jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/app
                    </value>
            </property>
            <property name="username">
                    <value>${USERNAME}</value>
            </property>
            <property name="password">
                    <value>${PASSWORD}</value>
            </property>
    </bean>

 EOF
 echo "Done."
```